# Get command output into variable

Tags: bash

In bash I got all the names from services which are balanced from /etc/haproxy. But now I want to store all these intro a $srv variable in order to continue my healthcheck script.

```
for filename in /etc/haproxy/*.cfg; do
    for ((i=0; i<=0; i++)); do
      srv = $(echo $filename | awk -F'[/.]' '{print $4}')
      echo $srv
    done
done
```

Using echo $filename | awk -F'[/.]' '{print $4}' is showing the correct microservices names like:
service1
service2
service3

Comment: No spaces around the `=` in shell assignments.

Comment: Change line-3: to `srv="$(echo "$filename" | awk -F'[/.]' '{print $4}')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have spaces around the `=` in shell variable assignments. What you wrote is trying to run the `srv` command, not assign to the `srv` variable. It should be:

```
srv=$(echo $filename | awk -F'[/.]' '{print $4}')
```

Comment: How do you learn shell scripting without such basic information?

Comment: I use only chef and ruby. But apparently there are VMs were you cannot set ruby environments and you have to deal with bash:) Last time I got blocked at the exact same step but I found a way around with some percona healthchecks. Thanks again!